# Problems with sendmail on CentOS 5

Tags: centos, sendmail

I am running a server with CentOS 5 with Plesk 10.1.1 (64-bit). The only change to the system recently has been upgrades to Plesk. I am having awful problems with doing a mass mailing recently.

When I run a test script using the php mail function in a simple script it takes 5 seconds to complete ( sending one email ).

When I tested sendmail with

```
strace sendmail -t leo@gmail.com < test.msg
```

The pause seems to occur on the wait4 command.

```
write(4, "Date: 16 Mar 2011 00:11:57 +0000"..., 190) = 190
close(4)                                = 0
write(6, "Froot@s15321728.onlinehome-serve"..., 62) = 62
close(6)                                = 0
wait4(25648, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 25648
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

My knowledge of server is rather limited, could someone point me where the issue might lay?

The message headers are

```
Delivered-To: leo@gmail.com
Received: by 10.204.23.201 with SMTP id s9cs151609bkb;
        Tue, 15 Mar 2011 17:08:51 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.216.25.210 with SMTP id z60mr4210560wez.104.1300234130914;
        Tue, 15 Mar 2011 17:08:50 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <root@s15321728.onlinehome-server.info>
Received: from s15321728.onlinehome-server.info (s15321728.onlinehome-server.info [87.106.200.40])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id m29si630437wej.135.2011.03.15.17.08.49
        (version=TLSv1/SSLv3 cipher=OTHER);
        Tue, 15 Mar 2011 17:08:49 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of root@s15321728.onlinehome-server.info designates 87.106.200.40 as permitted sender) client-ip=87.106.200.40;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of root@s15321728.onlinehome-server.info designates 87.106.200.40 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=root@s15321728.onlinehome-server.info
Received: (qmail 23890 invoked by uid 0); 16 Mar 2011 00:08:42 +0000
Date: 16 Mar 2011 00:08:42 +0000
Message-ID: <20110316000842.23887.qmail@s15321728.onlinehome-server.info>
From: root@s15321728.onlinehome-server.info
```

The contents of /etc/hosts are

```
127.0.0.1       s15321728.onlinehome-server.info        s15321728        localhost localhost.localdomain
```

Comment: How is DNS response on your machine?  Slow?  How about disk access?

Comment: +1 for the DNS comment. You should check your /etc/resolv.conf, /etc/nsswitch.com and /etc/hosts. Posting the headers from the test mail would also help.

Comment: How do I test DNS response ( sorry ). The correct nameservers are in resolv.conf

Comment: In the command line type host -t mx a_domain_name and if the response is slow, maybe the first nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf is in trouble. Do also a host -t ptr 4.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa where 1.2.3.4 is your IP address.

Comment: host -t mx command was super fast

host -t ptr 4.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa resolves instantly to correct address

Comment: Remove s15321728.onlinehome-server.info from the 127.0.0.1 line in /etc/hosts

Comment: Thats it! Mailing to 7000 customers now takes 30 seconds, can you post this as an answer and I'll accept. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your host's name (s15321728.onlinehome-server.info) from the 127.0.0.1 line in /etc/hosts